# Make init.d service wait for mount via systemd-logic

Tags: systemd, services, sysvinit

I have a `systemd`-based distribution (`debian 10`) with a legacy `init.d`-service (`backuppc`). As the backup is stored on an external drive, I'd like to ensure that the backup service does not run before the respective backup partition is mounted, is paused when it the mount is not available and restarted once it comes back up.

As `backuppc` is an existing package as is, migrating the `init.d`-script to `systemd` is not an option - also since I fear problems with reliability which obviously is essential for a backup system.

**Questions**

- Is there an (elegant) way to make a legacy `init.d`-service depend on a mount in `systemd`-logic?
- Can one conditionally start/stop another service based on prerequirements (exiting mount) via ONE single other service/target?
- Is the following approach reliable?

---

My current idea is the following:

1. **A `check-mount.target` which**

   - succeds and fails with the mount existence
   - (re)mounts if need be
   - comes before the backup service
   - starts the backup service
2. **A `stop-backup.service` which**

   - checks active status of `check-mount.target`
   - stops backup service if mount not active
3. **A timer to restart `check-mount.target`**

---

So this is what it looks like:

```
#check-mount.target
[Unit]
Description="starts backuppc if mount is present, fails otherwise"
BindsTo=backup_data.mount
After=backup_data.mount
Before=backuppc.service
Wants=backuppc.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
#stop-backup.service
[Unit]
Description="stops backup if mount is NOT present"

[Service]
#stop backup service if check-mount.target failed/is not active
ExecCondition=/usr/bin/bash -c '! /usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet backup_data.mount'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl stop backuppc
#restart will fail as long as mount is present:
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
#timer for check-mount.target
OnUnitInactiveSec=10
Unit=check-mount.target

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

What I don't like about this / Other findings:

- It needs two services and a timer with one of the services constantly restarting itself
  => I'd prefer simple dependencies that are mutually triggered
- Using a `Conflicts=backuppc` in `stop-backup.service` is not possible as the conflict is executed before doing the `ExecCondition`-test. I.e. the backup service is always stopped.
- AFAIK `systemd` does not offer `NOT`-logics, i.e. a `BindsTo=*NOT*backup_data.mount` where a service is started if the other fails and vice versa is not possible (but would simplify stopping the backup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be pretty straightforward to write a systemd service file that just calls the init.d startup script functions:

```
* ExecStart= -> start function
* ExecStop= -> stop function
* ...
```

This would in turn make it trivial to rely on systemd-specific instructions such as After=, Wants= or Require=

This question even shows how to include the init.d block into an empty systemd service file to have systemd magically do the right thing: https://serverfault.com/questions/690155/whats-the-easiest-way-to-make-my-old-init-script-work-in-systemd

Comment: Uff. Yes, using the `[Unit]`-dependencies of my `check-mount.target` and then just `ExecStart` to start the `init.d`-script AND **`ExecStopPost`** to stop it, will render `stop-backup.service` useless. The timer remains as is. If I read the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) correctly, `ExecStopPost` is necessary to also account for "unexpectedly" ending of the service and `ExecStop` is not sufficient.